# TF.exe Get changed files list only of given label by command line

Tags: tfs, tf-cli

How can we get the changed files list only, of given TFS Label.
I also wanted to know is there any way by which we can get the label just before the given label and the changed files list.
Can we also get the difference between two labels.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I count at least 3 to 4 questions here. It would be better to ask them separately - some people may know answers to one, but not the other.

Answer (score 1):

1. To get changed files of a given label: tf history "$/*serverPath*;L*LabelName*" /collection:"http://servername:8080/tfs/defaultcollection" /itemmode /format:detailed  /recursive /noprompt
2. You can use tf history versionspec to specify lables you want to check.
3. Get differences between two labels: tf diff "$/serverPath;LlabelnameA" "$/serverPath;LlabelnameB" /collection:"http://servername:8080/tfs/defaultcollection" /recursive /noprompt